# Any Browser I use fail to show google maps elements

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, ssl, tls

By default I am using Vivaldi browser.

On Vivaldi, when I go to maps.google.com, I can't see many regular widgets. For example the Street view man icon, and others.

I also can see there the search box but trying to use it to fly somewhere doesn't work for me.

**The strangest thing is that on all other browsers I have, I even cannot reach maps.google.com !**

On internet explorer I get:

> Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try
>   connecting to https://www.google.co.il  again. If this error persists,
>   it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher
>   suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered
>   secure. Please contact your site administrator.

Edge:

> Hmm, we can't reach this page.

And in Chrome:

> This site can’t be reached

Well, is it about TLS? How to solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't be positive about that, but I had a flash player update today and since then - everything is back for normal